# How to check if any element is None, or empty array, or False in a python iterable array (excluding zeros)?

Tags: python, arrays, nonetype

There is a list:

```
x = [5, "ce", 0, (32, "a")]
```

It doesn't contain a None, or empty array, or False element, so it should return `True`.

0 shouldn't be counted as an empty object.

```
y = [5, "ce", 0,, "", (32, "a")]
```

It contains an empty string so it should return `False`.

How would you do it in the fastest way?

Comment: Are you concerned about _this specific list_, or _any list in general_ that may contain zero, blank string, False values, empty sublists, etc?

Comment: I believe False == 0.

Comment: How about empty sequence, empty dict?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm interested in any list in general.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the same, it should count as None.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```py
>>> all(e not in [None, []] and e is not False for e in [5, "ce", 0, (32, "a")])
True
>>> all(e not in [None, []] and e is not False for e in [5, "ce", 0, 0, (32, "a")])
False
```

I noticed that there was a problem using `e not in [None, [], False]` because `0 in [None, [], False]` was giving `True`.